# Query JSONB columns with GORM for operator in

Tags: jsonb, go-gorm

I have a table like below

```
INSERT INTO switches VALUES ('33', 60, jsonb_build_object('IDs',jsonb_build_array('11', '2'),'ID', '33', 'Name', 'switch1'));
```

I have a struct/model

```
type switches struct {
    ID         string `gorm:"primary_key; unique; json:id"`
    Generation uint32 `gorm:"type:integer; column:generation;" json:"generation" `
    // Additional gorm type jsonb set, if not present causes field to be bytea
    SwitchAttrs []byte `sql:"type:jsonb; not null; column:Switch_attrs;" gorm:"type:jsonb; json:switchAttrs"`
}
```

I can query in postgres

```
SELECT * FROM switches WHERE switch_attrs->'IDs' ? '2' 
id | generation  |       data
----+-------+------------------
33 | 60 | {"IDs": ["33","2"] }
```

How do I construct a query on the jsonB column for a particular key(s)?  I was not able to find any documentation for using model objects to query which explains how to use "in" operator. I understand its possible to do with raw query, but wanted to see how it can be done using model object. I am trying to make queries like below but it fails :(

```
db = db.Where("Switch_attrs->'IDs' ?", "2").Find(&switches)
```

OR

```
db = db.Where("Switch_attrs->'IDs' ?",  []string{"2"}).Find(&switches)
```

OR

```
db = db.Where("Switch_attrs->'IDs' IN ?", []string{"2"}).Find(&switches)
```

OR

```
db = db.Where("Switch_attrs->>'IDs' ?",  "2").Find(&switches) . Note that i am querying as switch_attrs->>'IDs' . i expect the o/p as text and hence passing the value as "2".
```

for the last query i keep getting error as

> "Severity": "ERROR",   "Code": "42601",   "Message": "syntax error at
> or near "$1"",

Answer (score 2):

Redefine your model as below

```
type switches struct {
    ID         string `gorm:"primary_key; unique; json:id"`
    Generation uint32 `gorm:"type:integer; column:generation;" json:"generation" `
    // Additional gorm type jsonb set, if not present causes field to be bytea
    SwitchAttrs SwitchAttr `sql:"type:jsonb; not null; column:Switch_attrs;" gorm:"type:jsonb; json:switchAttrs"`
}
```

Add this for **SwitchAttr**

```
type SwitchAttr struct {
    data struct {
        ID   *int    `json:"id"`
        Generation *string `json:"generation"`
        IDs []string `json:"IDs"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

// Column JSONB field 
func (a SwitchAttr) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(a)
}

// simply decodes a JSON-encoded value into the struct fields.
func (a *SwitchAttr) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, &a)
}
```

For Query,

```
db = db.Where("switchAttrs @> '{"data":{"IDs":<pass_your_array_of_string>}}'::jsonb").Find(&switches)
```

Comment: is it really mandatory to modify the switchattrs.. i have lot of attributes which is stored as jsonb in switch_attrs and this is how i unmarshal.  ```  switches := make([]Switch, result.RowsAffected)
 for i, hciSwitch := range dbSwitches {
  unmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal(SwitchAttrs, &switches[i])```and the struct for switches is as below

Comment: ```type Switch struct {
 CustomerID      string                         
 Generation      int64                      
 ID              string                  
 IDs string                     
 SwitchName      string                       
 ResourceURI     string                   
 Type            string                         
 FirmwareVersion string                      
}```

Comment: sorry for bad indentation ,, it's really hard to provide code in comment section.. quite ease when posting a question

Comment: my point is the query fails even before we reach the marshal/unmarshal step. why can't i make query as i have pasted in the question.. i want to use switch_attrs->Ids way. can someone correct me if those query needs modification..

Comment: `is it really mandatory to modify the switchattrs`, obviously not but for this solution it is must